# Insert json file into mongodb specifying key to use as _id

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

I have some json which already has an ID that I want to insert into my mongo db.
The json is something like this

```
{"id" : 538748, 
 "event_date":"2016-07-02",
 "name" : "Tim"}
```

Is there any way to map the "id" to mongo's _id when inserting?

```
router.get('/newpage', function (req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('myDatabase');

request({
    url: "http://someurl.com/json",
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        // How to I specify the _id here
        collection.insert(body);

    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to modify the `body` doc you're inserting to effectively rename the `id` field to `_id`:

```
body._id = body.id;
delete body.id;
collection.insert(body);
```

But it's typically cleaner and safer to build up a new doc with just the valid fields, performing the mapping in the process:

```
var doc = {
    _id: body.id,
    event_date: body.event_date,
    name: body.name
};
collection.insert(doc);
```

Comment: Thank you I asked a friend from work and he told me the same! I only just earned my "Hello world" badge last night with node and mongo =]